# How to add multiple counters on the same page with different end dates

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using jCounter to create a countdown clock for auctions on my website.

To test it, I've set the counter on the footer like this:

```
$('[class^="countdown"]').jCounter({
    twoDigits: 'on',customDuration: 9999});
```

This works fine to set a single timer. The thing is, I have on the same page multiple auctions (which can be navigated in a slideshow using LiquidSlider) and I want to start a different countdown clock to each post, based on the date the auction ends. How can I achieve this? Is there any way to start a counter for each post inside the loop? Because it only works if I set it in the header or in the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your solution doesn't work you can try `.each()`  jQuery method:

```
$('[class^="countdown"]').each(function () {
    $(this).jCounter({
       twoDigits: 'on',
       customDuration: 9999
    });
});
```

Having the following HTML:

```
<ul class="countdown" data-duration="120">...</ul>
<ul class="countdown" data-duration="60">...</ul>
```

You will be able to do:

```
$('.countdown').each(function () {
    $(this).jCounter({
       twoDigits: 'on',
       customDuration: $(this).attr('data-duration')
    });
});
```

`$(this).attr('data-duration')` will return the value of the `data-duration` attribute for *each* `.countdown`.

Comment: That worked inside the loop, thanks a lot! But now I have a problem getting the data I need. Instead of customDuration now I have an end date for each post and I'm getting it like> date: '".get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'end_date', true)." <However, there is a problem setting the timer on the correct date for each post. For example, on POST 1, the time flashes between the correct one and the time of the next post. The POST 2 works fine. In POST 3 the timer doesn't start. If you want, take a look at the site at this [link](http://standcardeira.com/leiloes/zona-exclusiva/)

Comment: I will reply tomorrow. I have to sleep now.

Comment: Check out my answer.  You can put the end-date in the data-attribute.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. That edit worked, thanks a lot! I just changed customDuration to date on the jCounter parameters and put the post meta value with each end date in the data-duration attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If your html is coming from the server and you know the duration for each countdown, then you can add a data attribute with the duration and reference that via jQuery. For example:

HTML:

```
<div class=“countdown” data-duration=“60”>…</div>
```

Then you reference the attribute via jQuery like this:

```
$(".countdown").jCounter({
  twoDigits: 'on',
  customDuration: $('.countdown').attr('data-duration'),
  fallback: function() { console.log("count finished!") }
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GwFjV/